# Ubuntu vs Debian for a server

Tags: ubuntu, debian, linux

What are the pros and cons between Ubuntu and Debian for running a (http/mail/dns/nfs) server.

Comment: Which do you know better, or have access to people who know one better than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing:

I don't think that any distribution offers you a clear advantage for *any* purpose if you're only looking at the deployment of a few machines.  You're going to be running the same applications in virtually all instances, so you might as well pick whatever you're familiar with (or whatever your friends are familiar with), and concentrate on learning your applications.

If you're looking at a hosted/cloud solution, your selection of distribution may be limited by your selected service provider.